# Angular 2 System Config Paths Importing Custom Javascript Modules

Tags: angular

How do I import javascript files as modules in Angular 2?

Right now in my system config I have:

```
System.config({
  paths: {
    lodash: '../../node_modules/lodash/index.js',
    constants: 'app/constants.js'
},
```

I have a file `constants.js` which is:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class Constants{
  api_dir: string;

  constructor(){
      var prod = false;

      if (prod){
          this.root_dir = 'http://google.com/'
      } else{
          this.root_dir = 'http://localhost/'
      }
      this.api_dir = this.root_dir + 'api/'
    }
  }
```

In one of my components I have:

```
import {Constants} from 'constants';
```

Which gives me the error:

`Cannot find module 'constants'`

How do I turn a javascript file into a module so I can always import it without giving the relative path to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using typescript you would have to declare your module in a `.d.ts` file first. I supposed the error you're getting is a compiler one, not a runtime one.

```typescript
// ./constants.d.ts
declare module "constants" {
  // ... export whatever
  export interface IConstant {
    root_dir: string;
    api_dir: string;
  }
}
```

Otherwise your System config looks OK. If you want to avoid writing file extension everywhere, you can use `defaultJSExtensions = true` config option.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use explictly SystemJS API to register your module. Something like that, in your `app/constants.js` file:

```
System.register([], true, function(require, exports, module) {
  exports.Constants = {};
});
```

Comment: This would suppose a `register` output format which isn't the right way to write a module as it should be loader/bundler agnostic.